# Calculate the determinant of $\Phi$ with $\Phi(X) = AXB$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

Let $A,B\in M_n(\mathbb C)$ and $\Phi:M_n(\mathbb C)\to M_n(\mathbb C)$ such that $\Phi(X)=AXB$.

I tried to find $\det(Mat_\mathscr B(\Phi(\mathscr B)))$ with $\mathscr B=(E_{1,1},\dots,E_{n,1},\dots,E_{1,n},\dots,E_{n,n})$

($E_{i,j}$ is the matrix with a one in $(i,j)$ and zeros everywhere else)

I found that : $$\forall (i,j)\in[1,n], \Phi(E_{i,j}) = \sum_{p=1}^{n}\sum_{q=1}^{n} [A]_{p,i}[B]_{j,q}E_{p,q}$$

But I can't continue from there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Hint 1*. Writing $L_A(X)=AX$ and $R_B(X)=XB$, we have $\det(\Phi)=\det(L_A)\det(R_B)$.

(Arguably we should set $R_B(X)=XB^T$ because left/right stuff works out.)

*Hint 2*. For $L_A$ we can write $M_n$ as a direct sum of $n$ copies of $\mathbb{C}^n$, one for each possible column of $X$, and $L_A$ acts as $A$ on each of these copies of $\mathbb{C}^n$. In other words, in a nice choice of ordered basis, $L_A$ is represented block-diagonally with $n$ $A$s.

Comment: Oh okay now I understand ! So finding a composition really helps ! Thank you !